# How to parse multipart file upload android server side

Tags: android, file, upload, webserver

I am working on a webserver application where the user can upload a file to the android device from a browser.I believe that apache commons file upload can be used to parse a multipart form request on server side using servlets.Is there any way this can be done on android server side.I could get only  as far as consuming the request body.

```
                                -----------------------------4966737613931 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafile"; filename="log with spaces[ezees'.i]godknows.txt" Content-Type: text/plain 08-15 15:54:22.112: I/Process(650): Sending signal. PID: 650 SIG: 9 08-15 15:54:27.532: I/HTTPSERVICE(662): Creating and starting httpService 08-15 15:54:27.542: I/Notification(662): Notification Shown 08-15 16:08:19.332: I/HTTPSERVICE(662): Destroying httpService 08-15 16:08:19.352: I/Notification(662): Notification Destroyed 08-15 16:20:14.852: I/HTTPSERVICE(690): Creating and starting httpService 08-15 16:20:14.862: I/Notification(690): Notification Shown 08-15 16:20:28.102: D/dalvikvm(690): GC freed 2292 objects / 135976 bytes in 157ms 08-15 16:20:28.872: I/Resources(690): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 3090ms. 08-15 16:20:28.882: I/global(690): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required. 08-15 16:20:35.302: I/System.out(690): Host: localhost:8080 08-15 16:20:35.382: I/System.out(690): Accept-Encoding: gzip 08-15 16:20:35.422: I/System.out(690): Referer: http://localhost:8080/ 08-15 16:20:35.422: I/System.out(690): Accept-Language: en-US 08-15 16:20:35.442: I/System.out(690): User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.1-update1; en-us; sdk Build/ECLAIR) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17 08-15 16:20:35.472: I/System.out(690): Origin: http://localhost:8080 08-15 16:20:35.512: I/System.out(690): Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5 08-15 16:20:35.533: I/System.out(690): Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 08-15 16:20:35.562: I/System.out(690): Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7 08-15 16:20:35.599: I/System.out(690): Content-Length: 25 -----------------------------4966737613931--
```

Also this was a text file.What are the parsing intrinsics invloved in reading a file upload request manually using java ?I would like to get the file name and the file data from the request body.Any ideas or pointers in the right directions would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: depends on the framework you are using, mostly

Comment: @njzkI am using apache http core to build the android webserver.

Comment: I think mime4j http://james.apache.org/mime4j/ does the multipart parsing

Comment: @njzk2 I have had a look at their website but could not find any samples to parse a multipart file upload request.Would you please share a link to a working sample, if at all you have worked on this before.Thanks

Comment: that http://www.mozgoweb.com/posts/how-to-parse-mime-message-using-mime4j-library/ seems a complete example. just replace the file stream by the request stream

Comment: Thanks @njzk2 I will try that one and post back the results.